# Prevent a long-running ActionController from executing concurrently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3, concurrency

I have an action in a controller which could take a long time to complete.

I want to prevent two users from running it at the same time.

So far, I insert a record in the database when I start, and delete it when I'm done.

*What is a better way to do this?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move this to something in the background like DelayedJob to avoid locking your application, or you could make your database-driven lock more generic. That strategy doesn't seem too unreasonable, especially if it prevents your application from melting down.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using a rake task and cron to run my script.